# What do I set as JAVA_HOME?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ant, java-home

I just installed Ubuntu desktop 12.04 and installled Java 6 JDK via:

> sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre

When I issue a `java -version command, I get:

> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (6b24-1.11.3-1ubuntu0.12.04.1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

When I issue a 'which java` command, I get:

> /usr/bin/java

But when I go to `/usr/bin/`, I don't see a directory named `java`, so I don't think it's even there!?!

When I go to `/usr/lib/jvm/`, I see:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2387 Jun 27 05:21 .java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Aug 31 19:28 java-6-openjdk-amd64
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Aug 31 19:28 java-6-openjdk-common
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 Aug 31 19:28 java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

I'm now trying to add `JAVA_HOME` as an environmental variable to `~/.bashrc` so I can access it from inside my shell-based Ant builds:

> export JAVA_HOME=???

I'm not sure what to set as the value for `JAVA_HOME`:

- `/usr/bin/java`?
- `/usr/lib/jvm`?
- Something else?

By "`JAVA_HOME`", I mean the top-level directory of the JDK 6 install that I have on my system, wherever that is...

Comment: You just downloaded JRE6, so I would be inclined to think that you should set JAVA_HOME to /usr/lib/java-6-openjdk-common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have $JAVA_HOME configured on my Linux box - and I don't recall a time ever needing to do so.

When you're looking in `/usr/bin`, you're looking at binaries - hence **bin**.  A quick look at what the file is would reveal that it's a symbolic link, which points a symbolic link which points to wherever your Java installation resides.

```
$ file `which java`
/usr/bin/java: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java'
```

It is a better choice to let the system configure it for you - either through the use of [update-alternatives](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) or [update-java-alternatives](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/8/update-java-alternatives/) - the latter being preferred to switch over entire versions of Java entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Let the system configure it for you

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

For further reference, see [Choosing the default Java to use](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Choosing_the_default_Java_to_use) of the Ubuntu documentation.